# Do US born children whose parents are NOT citizens get automatic citizenship at birth?

Tags: united-states, citizenship

If you immigrate to the USA, will the baby get automatic citizenship? Wouldn't that kind of be a loophole?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthright_citizenship_in_the_United_States

Comment: As George White answered, it's not a loophole, it's intentional.

Comment: This isn't unique to the US: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_soli

Comment: If you look up [_Jus Soli_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_soli) and [_Jus Sanguinis_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_sanguinis) and [this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_soli#/media/File:Jus_soli_world.svg) in Wikipedia, you will see that the United States' rules are common in the Americas and much less common in other places.

Comment: @Flydog57 "*much less common in other places*" Geographically, perhaps, but population-wise, it looks like ~50% of the world is covered by the doctrine, at least with restrictions.

Comment: @justhalf it *was* intended in the 19th century, when travel to the US took months, not hours. Today the same law *is* [used as a loophole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_tourism).

Comment: @TrangOul not really loophole, since the immigration officer can deny you entry if they suspect you of planning to do this.

Comment: Actually, any children born in the US territory, which might be not only the mainland, but a US military base (John McCain), embassy, airplane, ship, etc. Note that this doesn't automatically mean citizenship for their parents.

Comment: @RogerVadim John McCain was born in a US territory, not just on a military base (but he would have been a US citizen no matter where he was born because his parents were US citizens).  Airplanes, ships, and indeed military bases are not US territory unless they happen to be located in US territory.

Comment: @phoog Not exactly a base, but still not the mainland: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_life_and_military_career_of_John_McCain#Family_heritage He would have been a citizen via his parents, but his right for presidency could have been questioned in this case.

Comment: @RogerVadim and it was questioned, though not seriously.  The consensus seems to be that "natural born" means "from birth" (such a person is never naturalized) so a US citizen child of US citizen parents is eligible regardless of the place of birth (see also Ted Cruz and George Romney). This has never been decided unambiguously by a court, but people advancing contrary arguments are typically crackpots or, at best, on the fringe. Certainly, the concept of "natural born" long predates the 14th amendment's guarantee of citizenship for those born in the US, so conflating the two is anachronistic.

Comment: @phoog this is very precise, but deviates from the subject. My remark was pointing out the scope of the "territory" where one gets the US citizenship by birth.

Comment: @RogerVadim but your remark was incorrect.  14th amendment citizenship arises only in the US proper; citizenship in the territories is governed by [statute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/chapter-12/subchapter-III/part-I).  And US military bases, embassies, airplanes and ships _are not US territory_ for the purpose of the 14th amendment nor the INA.  A child of non-US parents born in any of these places is not a US citizen (unless the base is in the US, the ship is in US territorial waters, or the plane is in US airspace). See https://fam.state.gov/FAM/08FAM/08FAM030101.html

Comment: @phoog why do you explain this to me? Write an answer.

Comment: The actor Sydney Poitier (who died less than two years ago) was born earlier than expected when his mother was a foreigner visiting Florida. That is why he was a citizen of the United States.

Answer (score 36):

Yes, the [Fourteenth Amendment](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/amendmentxiv) makes a person born on U.S. soil a U.S. citizen at the moment of birth.

> All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States.

This is not a "loophole," because it is exactly what the drafters of the Fourteenth Amendment were trying to achieve.

There are narrow exceptions because of the "subject to the jurisdiction thereof" clause:

> The children of an ambassador are held to be subjects of the prince whom he represents, although born under the actual protection and in the dominions of a foreign prince. ... Thus the children of enemies, born in a place within the dominions of another sovereign, then occupied by them by conquest, are still aliens.

[*Inglis v. Trustees of Sailor's Snug Harbour*, 28 U.S. 99, 155-56 (1830)](https://casetext.com/case/inglis-v-trustees-of-sailors-snug-harbour).

Comment: It's not so clear-cut that they were trying to make it easier for the children of immigrants to get citizenship.  You have to remember that it was ratified in 1868.  The big subject of the day was how to handle citizenship of former slaves.

Comment: @Ryan_L yeah, remember that the amendment was passed after the Civil Rights act of 1866 had to be passed over a presidential veto and the abolitionist Congress was worried that a future Congress could repeal it, so they wrote it into the Constitution while they had a super-majority. In the act, it read "all persons born in the United States and not subject to any foreign power, excluding Indians not taxed, are declared to be citizens of the United States", the amendment was supposed to have the same meaning, but written more concisely, since amendments are short.

Comment: @Ryan_L The supreme court decided (6-3) to interpret it literally, but if 2 members had been different, or if it's re-examined in the future, they could rule that the intent of amendment was that "and subject to the jurisdiction thereof"=="not subject to any foreign power, excluding Indians not taxed"(native Americans weren't US citizens until a separate act of Congress the 1920s because they were citizens of their own nations), then anyone already a foreign subject because of inherited citizenship, would not be born a US citizen.

Comment: @Eugene The Supreme Court won’t do that. “Maybe the Supreme Court will overturn two hundred years of law in a way that causes huge problems,” is pure wishful thinking. You can always say, “Maybe the law will change in the future! Someday!” Or maybe they’ll rule that AIs are people guaranteed citizenship under the Fourteenth Amendment. That’s irrelevant to what the law is now.

Comment: @Davislor they overturned Plessy v. Ferguson and Dredd Scott.

Comment: In the days of *Wong Kim Ark*, it was simply assumed that US-born children of immigrants from Europe were US citizens, even if their parents still had foreign citizenship. The only real controversy in *Wong Kim Ark* was whether being born to parents who are permanently ineligible for US citizenship was somehow one of the exceptions to the Citizenship Clause. Evidently, the common understanding of the Fourteenth Amendment did not contain a "not a national of any foreign country" clause.

Comment: The Court also noted in that case that the jurisdiction of any sovereign state in its own territory is exclusive. So if you're born in the US, it means that at the moment of your birth, you're not actually "subject to any foreign power" even if that country considers you to be one of its "subjects". The children of diplomats are excepted because they're still under the jurisdiction of the sending country even while they're in the US.

Comment: @Davislor given what the current supreme court has already overturned, never say never. I was just pointing out that there are other interpretations of the 14th amendment out there.

Comment: @Eugene That one’s not really in the mainstream. John Eastman supported it, and he *used* to be a law professor before he was forced to resign over his unethical conduct. But he’s usually dismissed as a crackpot. We can always speculate that the court might do anything. Maybe it’ll rule that animals are people, too! Maybe it’ll rule that, because women didn’t have the right to own property when the Fifth or Fourteenth Amendments were enacted, they still don’t!

Comment: @Davislor I have not heard of John Eastman, but I've encountered that interpretation of the 14tha lot in conservative media. And equating the idea of the same supreme court that overturned roe v Wade, reinterpreting the 14th amendment to recognizing animals as people is facetious and you know it.

Comment: @Davislor haven't they already ruled that many utterances are not protected by the First Amendment?

Comment: The diplomats rule works both ways, incidentally, as children born to US diplomats (or military servicemen) who were on duty on foreign soil still count as US citizens as well.  E.g. John McCain, born in the Panama Canal Zone, was not barred from running for President because of that.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: "as children born to US diplomats (or military servicemen) who were on duty on foreign soil still count as US citizens as well." Only if their US citizen parent(s) meet the conditions to transmit US citizenship to a child born abroad. There is no difference in treatment between children of US diplomats or servicemen, and children of other US citizens born abroad.

Comment: @user102008 but then there's 8 USC 1401(g), applying to the child born outside the US of an alien and a US citizen, where "any periods of honorable service in the Armed Forces of the United States, or periods of employment with the United States Government or with an international organization as that term is defined in section 288 of title 22 by such citizen parent, [or where the US citizen parent was the dependent child and a member of the household of someone so serving,] may be included in order to satisfy the physical-presence requirement of this paragraph."

Comment: @phoog: Oh right, I forgot about that. Time in service or as the dependent of someone in service counts as physical presence in the US, and so a long period of service makes it more likely they will meet the physical presence requirement when they have the child (makes no difference if the parent is on duty or not at that time), but not all diplomats or servicemen will meet the physical presence requirement to pass on citizenship.

Comment: The biggest loophole to "subject to the jurisdiction thereof" is the US territories. They must be statutorily granted citizenship rights, which has not happened to American Samoa. Individuals born there, absent some other claim to citizenship, become US nationals instead.

Comment: @user71659 actually the reason for the difference is not "subject to the jurisdiction thereof," since those territories and the people in them certainly are subject to the jurisdiction of the United States.  The distinction is that the territories are "unincorporated," meaning that they are not "in the United States" for the purpose of the 14th amendment (among several other purposes).

Comment: I might be inclined to believe that if you cited a source.

Answer (score 19):

Not a loophole but the intent of the constitution.

> Fourteenth Amendment, Section 1: All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States and of the State wherein they reside.

It might seem odd to you because many other countries are less generous with their citizenship.

Do note the caveat. It means children born to foreign diplomats do not get automatic citizenship.

Comment: And children belonging to invading armies, I believe. Not sure when this happened the last time.

Comment: @gnasher729 Several thousand Japanese troops invaded Alaska during WWII and remained for about a year, though I don't know if any women were among the invading force. Most recent time before then would've been 1812.

Comment: Hey, I learned something new!

Comment: @TylerH Of course, the 14th Amendment didn't exist in 1812. To my knowledge there are no instances of anyone who is part of an invading army giving birth in the United States ever since the 14th Amendment was adopted. Incidentally, there is also a statutory provision that also gives citizenship to people in the position of Clark Kent a.k.a. Superman who are found unaccompanied in the U.S. at a very young age when the circumstances of their birth and parents are unknown. The Indians not taxed exemption from birthright citizenship was repealed by statute in 1924.

Comment: To be exact, children born to foreign diplomats currently serving and enjoying diplomatic immunity are not eligible to gain citizenship through the 14th Amendment. It does not preclude deriving citizenship through the other parent if they are a US citizen, nor does it concern anyone who has a parent that held a diplomatic post but at the time of birth was a private citizen. Likely the bar extends to the sovereign of another nation is also covered under this and not just their official representatives but we really haven't tested that part legally.

Comment: @ohwilleke It would have been amusing watching ICE officers trying to arrest Superman;-)

Comment: It's not a loophole because they had just had a big war which freed the slaves, and the 14th Amendment *established* citizenship of former slaves. Without that amendment they could be made stateless.

Comment: @TylerH would be interesting if a Japanese soldier (being an enemy) impregnated a woman who was not a US citizen (say a Canadian) living in Japanese occupied territory. Would be an extreme corner case.

Comment: @jwenting the amendment says nothing about the *parents* being subject to the jurisdiction

Comment: The US is only "generous" with citizenship by birth, whereas in many other ways it's far less generous towards immigrants than other countries: e.g. getting a work permit is far more difficult compared to other countries, never mind the human rights violations at immigrant detainment facilities.

Comment: "many other countries are less generous with their citizenship" However, almost all countries in the Americas *are* this "generous" with their citizenship. So the US is not unusual if you look at it that way.

Comment: @TylerH Alaska wasn't a state until 1959, long after the Japanese invasion.  And I think the 14th Amendment does not control the citizenship of persons born in territories and possessions of the U.S.

Comment: @MarkDominus: The "United States" in the Citizenship Clause of the 14th Amendment includes all incorporated territories, and Alaska was an incorporated territory. Also, the statutes that provide for birthright citizenship (which clearly included Alaska) also had the "subject to the jurisdiction thereof" clause.

Comment: @user253751 The courts have determined that this was what was intended from the Amendment's language.

Comment: @JimZhou the US-born child of a foreign diplomat and a US citizen does obtain citizenship under the 14th amendment because the US spouse of the foreign diplomat has no diplomatic immunity.  Regarding "nor does it concern anyone who has a parent that held a diplomatic post but at the time of birth was a private citizen," it also doesn't concern anyone who has a diplomatic post somewhere else but is visiting the US for personal reasons.  For example if the Mexican ambassador to Canada gives birth in the US while she is on vacation under a B-2 visa, her child is a US citizen.

Comment: @ohwilleke have they?  It's difficult to tell because the family members of a diplomat are also afforded diplomatic immunity.  I believe it is the child's personal immunity from US jurisdiction that triggers the exception of the 14th amendment, but since the child's immunity stems from the parent's, it's hard to say for sure. The question becomes significant if a foreign diplomat has a child with a US-citizen spouse, which leads to a chicken-and-egg question, because alien members of that family are immune, but US-citizen members are not.  Which is the child?

Comment: @phoog Thanks for agreeing with me, I guess? If the child is born to parents who both enjoy diplomatic immunity (by virtue of being holders of A-1 visas), then it would create a rebuttable presumption of non-citizenship provided that there is an alternative manner to derive citizenship (many USCs do not know that they are USCs). There's discretion to it but the current policy is that spouses of A-1 gets A-1 as well. A-1 visa is not equivalent to status such as LPR snf do derivation sans jus soli is quite possible. I don't disagree with your last assertion, since B-2 != A-1.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, children born in the territory of the United States automatically become U.S. citizens by the [14th Amendment](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/amendment-14/#:%7E:text=No%20State%20shall%20make%20or,equal%20protection%20of%20the%20laws).

It is not a "loophole" in that, while the child is a U.S. citizen, their parents can still be deported.

The U.S.-born children of immigrants cannot sponsor their parents for a green card until they are at least 21 years of age or older. [Source](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/guides/A1en.pdf)

> As a citizen of the United States, you may help a relative become
> a lawful permanent resident of the United States by obtaining what
> is often referred to as a “Green Card.” To do so, you need to sponsor
> your relative and be able to prove that you have enough income
> or assets to support your relative(s) when they come to the United
> States.

If eventually granted a green card, the parents must be a permanent resident for five years before they can apply for naturalization **or** be a permanent resident for at least 3 years and married to a US citizen (who is [not your descendant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_incest_in_the_United_States#:%7E:text=No%20person%20shall%20marry%20his,is%20not%20a%20criminal%20offense.)). [Source](https://www.uscis.gov/forms/uscis-early-filing-calculator#:%7E:text=You%20may%20file%20Form%20N,married%20to%20a%20US%20citizen.)

A common (derogatory) term for this is "Anchor Baby".

Comment: "children born in the territory of the United States". You have to be careful with that phrasing because a "territory of the United States" means something different. A territory is a non-state area, like Puerto Rico. Those are _not_ subject to the 14th Amendment. Citizenship has been statutorily granted to people born in most of the inhabited territories, the outlier is currently American Samoa. There people born there do not gain US citizenship absent any other means of claim, but rather US nationality.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately yes. My daughter did not have the choice and became a citizen of this country. Now 30 years later she has lots of problems because of that citizenship. There is an association called Accidental Americans working for those citizens who do not want being citizens of the US. Check out the wiki page for Accidental Americans. Repudiating this citizenship is not easy and quite expensive.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your situation properly, but the parents do have the choice and can decide if they want their kids to be an American citizen or not. When my friend's kids, who were not US citizens but working there, were born in the US, they just applied for indian passports for them and the kids became indian citizens. If they had opted for American citizenship and passports for their kids, I guess they would have got that.

Comment: The edit by @sfxedit is incorrect. For a person born in the US who's parents are not foreign diplomats, citizenship is automatic at birth, and the procedure to renounce it is elaborate.

Comment: @GerardAshton I looked it up and you are partly right. Parents cannot decide the citizenship of the kids. What my friends probably meant was how easy India makes it to opt for indian citizenship, once the kid turn 18, if the parents follow some simple procedures after their birth. More info here - [Indian Citizenship for US Born Child](https://www.am22tech.com/indian-citizenship-us-born-child/).

Comment: @sfxedit that doesn't mean the child loses their US citizenship, which is extremely hard and expensive to get rid of. They'd end up most likely with dual citizenship and having to pay income tax in 2 countries (which is one of the main disadvantages of US citizenship when living abroad with dual citizenship).

Comment: @jwenting Yes, as the link I cited pointed out, I understand what you all mean that one doesn't automatically lose US citizenship. India however doesn't allow dual citizenship (and has a double tax avoidance treaty with the usa which means we only need to pay tax either in US or India) so that's one less headache for indian parents working in America.

Comment: @sfxedit :) Netherlands too doesn't allow dual citizenship UNLESS it's impossible or extremely expensive (as with the US) to denounce your other citizenship. So there are dual Dutch/US citizens. Many countries have similar provisions (one of my friends is dual Japanese/US for example, despite Japan not allowing dual citizenship).

Comment: @jwenting That's really interesting. I wonder how it works - are they allowed to have two passports?

Comment: @jwenting I wouldn't say that. While for the Netherlands single citizenship is the norm, there are many exceptions that allow dual citizenship and it's not only in impossible or expensive cases. Some of them are a bit weird, like for example, I'm a Dutch person living in Denmark right now. If I would apply for Danish citizenship I would normally lose my Dutch one yes. But if I were to marry my Danish girlfriend first and then apply for Danish citizenship I will keep my Dutch citizenship

Comment: @sfxedit yes, both Japanese and US travel documents. And visa free entry in both Japan and the USA, obviously. Not sure what'd happen if they needed to travel to a country where you need a visa as a citizen of one but not the other, would be an interesting one for immigration lawyers to dwell on.

Comment: @jwenting In general, being a citizen of a visa-free country is enough. There are are a few exceptions when the country you want to enter _really does not like™_ one of the countries you hold a passport of (or sometimes even just visited), so for instance if you have a passport for Syria, North Korea or a few countries the US does not like, even if you have a UK or EU passport for instance you will have a hard time getting an ESTA.

Comment: @jwenting the Netherlands allows dual citizenship from birth without regard to the difficulty of relinquishing the other citizenship, along with some other exceptions as noted by Ivo.  As to visa requirements for dual citizens, you're generally treated as a citizen of whichever passport you present.  An American/Bangladeshi dual citizen can travel to the Schengen area without a visa using a US passport but requires a visa if using a Bangladeshi passport.

Comment: @jcaron but disqualification for the VWP can also arise by simply traveling to certain countries.  And truly visa exempt travelers (Canadians and Bermudians) remain visa exempt regardless of their travel history or other nationality.

Comment: @sfxedit: According to section 4 of India's Citizenship Act, a child born abroad to at least one Indian citizen parent, can be registered as an Indian citizen by descent at an Indian consulate within 1 year of birth, with the declaration that the child does not possess a foreign passport. So the parent needs to opt for this soon after birth, not at 18, but it does not mean anything about the child's US citizenship -- if the child is born in the US, the child will still be automatically and involuntarily a US citizen, in addition to being an Indian citizen.

Comment: @sfxedit: According to section 4 subsection (1A) of India's Citizenship Act, an Indian citizen by descent needs to renounce their other citizenships, if any, within 6 months of turning 18, or they automatically lose Indian citizenship. That may be what you are thinking of when you said 18.

Answer (score 7):

That all those born in the US having citizenship being a constitutional right is generally based on the Fourteenth Amendment, which says "All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States." There is some debate as to what exactly the "subject to the jurisdiction thereof" qualification means. It has been interpreted as not granting citizenship to the children of parents who have diplomatic immunity, and there are some of the position that it also requires the parents' presence in the US to be legal, and/or open and notorious, but that view has little support in the legal community. There is also the issue of what counts as "the United States". While people in America Samoa are US nationals, courts have denied them citizenship. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Samoan_citizenship_and_nationality#Federal_citizenship_controversy_(1960%E2%80%93present)

There are indeed people who travel to the US late in their pregnancy specifically to give birth in the US and thus have their children be US citizens. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_tourism . There is also the term "anchor baby", which is generally used in a derogatory manner to refer to children of immigrants who were born in the US (though not necessarily implying that the parents immigrated for the purpose of having the child in the US).

Comment: "there are some of the position that it also requires the parents' presence in the US to be legal": none of those people are judges, however.  Supreme court precedent on this matter is clear.  American Samoans are also denied US citizenship not so much by courts as by Congress; the courts are just upholding the statutes.  Those born in outlying US territories do not gain citizenship under the 14th amendment; this is also clear.  Territories where people acquire citizenship by birth are covered by statutory provisions in the Immigration and Nationality Act.

Comment: Also "anchor baby" refers to children of _nonimmigrants_ (usually nonresident nonimmigrants, typically tourists) or illegal immigrants; there's no point in creating a so-called anchor if you're already a legal immigrant.

Comment: "American Samoans are also denied US citizenship not so much by courts as by Congress; the courts are just upholding the statutes." Statutes cannot override the constitution, so if "United States" in the 14th amendment included all territories, then people born in all territories would be US citizens, regardless of what statutes say. And what constitutes the "United States" in the 14th amendment is a matter of interpretation, since it is not defined explicitly. The current understanding is that it doesn't include unincorporated territories, but the courts could interpret it differently.

Comment: @user102008 good point.  The statutory provisions do indeed depend on the court's finding that the territories in question are not "the United States" in the sense of the 14th amendment (the "insular cases" if I understand correctly).  It is only in the context of that decision that congress has the power to grant citizenship to the people of those territories or to withhold it from them.

Answer (score 4):

IANAL, and this has already been well answered legally, but I wanted to give a personal example for historical context.

My aunt's parents emigrated to the U.S. from Italy in 1934, having delivered their oldest son on the ship while crossing the Atlantic from Italy, and my aunt was born a year later (1935) in New Castle PA.  Her older brother was thus not born in the U.S. and had to apply for citizenship years later.  My aunt, on the other hand, was a citizen by birth, *even though her parents had not yet become citizens themselves* and she never had to apply for it.

My point being that this is nothing new or special in America, it has been going on for hundreds of years and has applied to many hundreds of thousands of citizens, new-born to parents who were not citizens.

Comment: "it has been going on for hundreds of years": indeed, it was the rule under common law for centuries before the US came into being.  It's clear from the debates around the 14th amendment that legislators understood it to be extending that rule to all people regardless of race (while preserving the ancient exceptions for foreign diplomats and occupiers).  (The UK restricted its _jus soli_ in the early 1980s; until then it was basically the same.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems worth mentioning that birthright citizenship in the United States is part of the aftermath of the Civil War of 1861–1865. Part of the outcome of the war was the abolition of slavery. Earlier the Supreme Court had ruled in the case of Scott v. Sandford that negroes are not citizens, regardless of whether they are enslaved or not. Everything about the status of persons of African descent was a big issue in the aftermath of the war. Before that, different states had different laws about who was a citizen, although there were also federal naturalization laws. The 14th Amendment was intended to supersede much of that.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, as stated on the IRS.gov. Amendment XIV, Section 1, Clause 1 of the U.S. Constitution directs that all persons born in the United States are U.S. citizens. This is the case regardless of the tax or immigration status of a person's parents.